# What is the usage of "clearOldDexDir" in MultiDex#install?

Tags: android

I am reading the source code of [MultiDex](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/master/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.java). There is a procedure of  **clearOldDexDir(context)** nearing line 153, whose function is to delete directory **/data/data//files/secondary-dexes**.

However, I can't find any code that create files in **/data/data//files/secondary-dexes**. The MultiDex does this procedure any time the Application runs but it seems to be nonsense.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain to us what is it you are trying to do? Have you checked the documentation on this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html), and have you also looked at how it's generally used like [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found the answer myself. Support MultiDex will use "/data/data//code_cache/secondary-dexes" at first, and if it failed it try "/data/data//files/secondary-dexes".

Therefore MultiDex delete "/data/data//files/secondary-dexes" when it starts working.